# Cannot use JavaEdit.Object.setText (qtp vbs)

Tags: vbscript, edit, qtp

I am using QTP 11 for automation and I have come accross an issue I don't really know what to do with.

I am trying to set the value of a JavaEdit field using it's native setText method like so:

```
JavaWindow("Window").JavaEdit("Edit").Object.setText "value"
```

This has worked like this in the past, but now I keep getting "method not supported" errors at runtime. The objects exist in the object repository and are referred to correctly, and are visible in the application under test.

Does anyone know what might be the cause of this?

Comment: Is BHO Manager add on enabled in IE?

Comment: I'm not sure. But this is not a web application.

Comment: If you 'Spy' the object, do you see the method in the `Operations` list of the `Native Properties`? EDIT: Nevermind... why do old posts pop up in my 'Tag Submissions' list?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but as far as I remember it should be

```
JavaWindow("Window").JavaEdit("Edit").Object.setText(value)
```

in brackets. I might be mistaken though.
Could it be that the TextEdit has become read only?